# Sitecore Horizon failure on PopulateHorizonSearchSchema : SitecoreUrl

Tags: solr, horizon

Sitecore is installed, but `Horizon` keeps failing on the last step.
Is there something I should be checking to prevent this step from failing?

**The error I get:**

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Error requesting https://mysitecore.dev.local/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=sitecore_horizon_index: 
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
At C:\Sitecore Horizon 10.2.0 rev. 05608\InstallerModules.psm1:97 char:3
+   Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreCM -WorkingDirectory $workDi ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
     
[TIME] 00:00:25
Invoke-SitecoreUrlTask : Error requesting https://mysitecore.dev.local/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=sitecore_horizon_index: The 
remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
At C:\Users\summerb\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.3.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641 char:25
+                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-SitecoreUrlTask
```

Comment: What error is logged by the CM?

Comment: Do you mean this one?          Could not find type: Sitecore.Horizon.Integration.DependencyInjection.HorizonServiceConfigurator, Sitecore.Horizon.Integration [<configurator type="Sitecore.Horizon.Integration.DependencyInjection.HorizonServiceConfigurator, Sitecore.Horizon.Integration" patch:source="Sitecore.Horizon.Integration.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" />]

Comment: The sitecore log files (log.txt) that exist under `App_Data/logs` should provide details about the related error. You've only demonstrated that the installation script fails.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Is there something I should be checking to prevent this step from failing?**

   Yes, You can validate the `Prerequisites`

   - Install Sitecore Experience Platform 10.2.
   - Ensure that your Sitecore Content Management (CM) site is accessible with    the https protocol.
   - Enable support for the WebSocket Protocol in Windows Server Manager.
   - Ensure Sitecore Identity is installed.

   You must also install the following tools on the server where you plan to   install Horizon:

   - Sitecore Installation Framework (SIF) 2.3.0
   - ASP.NET Core/.NET Core: Runtime & Hosting Bundle 3.1.15 x64

   After you install the tools, restart your machine.

   You can find more details on Horizon installation guide: [OnPrem Installation Guide](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/9391D95789784200B5D0D9FDF0688E3E.ashx?date=20220223T152849)
2. **Regarding your error,** By looking the error details it looks the Horizon appointed to the `sitecore_horizon_index` but due to some error it might not created the solr core folder or not populated with index data with required configurations.

   You can try out below solution.

   1. To verify `sitecore_horizon_index`. [Where is the sitecore_horizon_index](https://stockpick.nl/english/where-is-the-sitecore_horizon_index/)
   2. Issue Pre and Post installation. [Sitecore Horizon Issue Pre and Post installation](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2022/07/sitecore-horizon-issue-pre-and-post-installation.html)
   3. Sitecore Horizon 10 Installation. [Step by step Sitecore Horizon 10 Installation](https://madhuanbalagan.com/sitecore-horizon-10-installation)

   **Knowledge sharing:**
   Horizon is no longer supported after XP 10.2 and is not included with XP 10.3. [Deprecated features in XP 10.3](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/what%27s-new/deprecated-features-in-xp-10-3.html)

   Hope it helps!